# FID error "imaginary component" in Google Colab - PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, metrics

I am reaching out to seek help with an unusual error I've encountered while trying to compute the FID score for a GAN project in Google Colab. I have been utilizing the repositories at https://github.com/mseitzer/pytorch-fid and https://github.com/GaParmar/clean-fid. However, both are returning an error related to an "imaginary component," despite using identical paths that, under normal circumstances, should yield a FID score of 1. **Interestingly, when I perform the same operation in Kaggle with the same dataset, I do not face this issue.**

Could you provide guidance on how to successfully compute the FID score in Google Colab using either of these libraries? Any advice or steps to troubleshoot this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

I've experimented with a variety of folders containing images of different sizes, but unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.

Edit:
This is some code for reproducibility.
First I Install clean-fid:

```
!pip install clean-fid
```

and then I mount drive folders:

```
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Finally, I compute the FID score:

```
from cleanfid import fid

score = fid.compute_fid("/content/drive/MyDrive/pathA", "/content/drive/MyDrive/cyclegan/pathB")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem I encountered, as detailed in the issue here: https://github.com/bioinf-jku/TTUR/issues/4.

It remains unclear why the computation of the covariance matrix succeeds on Kaggle but fails on Colab. Nonetheless, considering that my datasets are relatively small, ranging from 200 to 1000 samples, I've decided finally to use the Kernel Inception Distance (KID), that provides a reliable and unbiased score. It performs well on Colab without any issues. Given this experience, I recommend using KID for scenarios where the sample size is limited

Comment: is there any open source implementation for Kernel Inception Distance (KID) available?